# Top 10% of runners in a race - easy question, but need confirmation

Tags: statistics

Suppose there are 100 runners in a race. And the last time ran by the runners is $60 \,s$. Top $10\%$ of runners will get a prize. I want to use my (cumulative frequency) diagram to estimate this.

Some people argue that the answer is just $10$, $10\%$ of $100 = 10$ so top $10$ runners is ten. However, wouldn't it be more reasonable to say that the top $10\%$ of runners are those that finish in under $6$ seconds?

What would be the difference in phrasing that indicates which one is being asked for?

Thanks.

Comment: What is "this" in "... to estimate this"? You say "Some people argue that the answer is just 10" - but what in fact is the *question*?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The top 10% of runners that will get a prize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"top $10\%$ of runners" are for sure the runners that rank in the best $10\%$ (top $20$ if there are $200$ runners). For the other (really weird) meaning you'd need to state "runners whose time is within $10\%$ of the worst time". You can win the race, but you won't know if you are in this absurd top $10$ until you know the time of the last runner.

Comment: That's true, thank you.